# Stripes in Landsat-image after topographic correction (SAGA)

Tags: raster, saga

I got stripes in my topographic corrected Landsat images (see second image below). 
I used SAGA GIS 2.0.8 at xubuntu 12.04

Image and DEM are in the same projection, tried it with  EPSG:32636 and EPSG:4326

[image: original Landsat image]

[image: topo corrected Landsat image]

Comment: Did you used the same pixel resolution for both dem and landsat?

Comment: Ahhh, thats a point: landsat has a cell size of 30, the DEM of 28. How do I change the DEM cell size to 30?

Comment: You need to resample the DEM to the Landsat resolution (e.g. with the bilinear method if provided by SAGA).

Comment: Thats it! The different pixel resolution was the reason for the stripes. This question can be marked as answered!

Comment: Please post the SAGA process as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the resolution of the image and the DEM (open the image/DEM and look a the description under "cell size"). It should be the same, if not:

Align the resolution of the image and the DEM using (SAGA)
"Grid" -> "Construction" -> "Resampling" 
Then choose the image or DEM you want to resample and set "user defined" at "Target Grid" and start. A new window opens. At "Cellsize" write the resolution you want (in my case it was the resolution of the Landsat image with 30m per pixel).
 [image]
Now the image and the DEM should have the same resolution (cellsize) and you can now proceed with the topographic correction...